# How can I use a Java List with Scala's foreach?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have tried to convert a java list to a Scala list without success using asInstanceOf, as my returned list from an android call is a java list.

```
val apList = (wfm.getScanResults:java.util.List[ScanResult])
```

Wish to do this so that I can use the (new Scala) list in a for comprehension as it doesn't seem to like using a java list in this construct giving me an error.

```
value foreach is not a member of java.util.List[android.net.wifi.ScanResult]
    for (ap<-apList) { .... }
         ^
```

Is their a way to use a Java list in a for/foreach, without coercing it? And if I have to coerce, how? as asInstanceOf invokes a r/t error when used in this way.

Comment: Great question.  I was wondering why my for comprehensions weren't working (individual entries couldn't be extracted with the proper type even though the list used generics).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a set of conversions under [`scala.collection.JavaConversions`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConversions$) and [`scala.collection.JavaConverters`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$) packages. First one acts implicitly on collection, the last one intends to be used explicitly (you take java collection and turn it to the scala analog with `.asScala` method and vice versa with `.asJava`).

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala> val xs = new java.util.ArrayList[Int]()
// xs: java.util.ArrayList[Int] = []
xs.add(1)
xs.add(2)
// java.util.ArrayList[Int] = [1, 2]

scala> for(x <- xs) println(x)
1
2
```

And by the way, the reason asInstanceOf doesn't work is because [scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_1.html) and java collections have entirely different hierarchy and class cast cannot be made. Scala list has no other similarities with Java list except one common predecessor: Object class, so it is no different from trying to cast List to, say, java.util.Random.

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Comment: This answer is out of date. I use `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` and `for(x <- xs.asScala)`

Comment: @AlbertHendriks : scala 2.12 doesnt support your import may be its 2.13  how to do it for scala 2.12

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram I suppose in 2.12 you can use Om-nom-nom's answer (otherwise I don't know), but it should be recommended to upgrade your Scala version, which is very old.